# Laravel service provider is no loading the Collection methods Undefined method 'values'.intelephense(1013)

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I want to make a Collection macro function in the service provider.
The problem is after importing the Collection class i can not access the collection funtion  **$this->values()**
But when I use the same code in the controller is working fine.

```
 <?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class CollectionExtensions extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
      
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
    Collection::macro('transpose', function () {
            $items = array_map(function (...$items) {
                return $items;
            }, ...$this->values());
        
            return new static($items);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `$this` is the `CollectionExtensions` class, not the method/function executing it...

Comment: @matiaslauriti, that's not correct. The Macroable trait uses [Closure::bind()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/closure.bind.php) to make `$this` resolve to the `Collection` instance rather than the class where the closure is defined. So that trait truly offers the functional equivalent of method-overloading.

Comment: Are you sure that CollectionExtensions Provider is listed in the app.php config? If so, I'd start by adding a `dd('testing...')` to the beginning of your `boot` method, just as a sanity-check to make sure it's actually getting executed.

Comment: @kmuenkel yes it's working when I dd('testing') in boot function.

Comment: I m basically following this article [link](https://adamwathan.me/2016/04/06/cleaning-up-form-input-with-transpose/)